# Pydantic set attribute/field to model dynamically

Tags: python, pydantic

According to the [docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/#options):

> **allow_mutation**
>
> whether or not models are faux-immutable, i.e. whether **setattr** is allowed (default: True)

Well I have a class :

```py
class MyModel(BaseModel):

    field1:int

    class Config:
        allow_mutation = True
```

If I try to add a field dynamically :

```py
model1 = MyModel(field1=1)
model1.field2 = 2
```

And I get this error :

```
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 347, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__setattr__
ValueError: "MyModel" object has no field "field2"
```

Obviously, using `setattr` method will lead to the same error.

```py
setattr(model1, 'field2', 2)
```

Output:

```py
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 347, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__setattr__
ValueError: "MyModel" object has no field "field2"
```

What did I miss here ?

Comment: Shouldn't the `setattr` call be on `model1` not `field2`, i.e., `setattr(model1, 'field2', 2)` ?

Comment: typo in the question : fixed ! Thanks @JoshClark. Issue still here of course

Comment: is that setattr allowed on **existing** fields? ie field1, not field2.  Try setting it to false, creating an instance and then setting field1 again on the instance.  Thats likely what it controls rather than adding **arbitrary** attrs.

Comment: @JLPeyret Does that mean that creating new fields on the fly is not possible ?

Comment: If what I suggest is correct, then yes it probably means that.  I use pydantic extensively but not yet very in very complex ways.  But it does not seem very intended to work with dynamic code, something I otherwise do a lot.  What about a `dynvars : dict[str,Any] = field(factory=dict)` not sure about the factory syntax and mutating with extra random fields?

Comment: @JLPeyret I finally found a kind of workaround. I posted it as an own answer. let me know your opinion about it if you can.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Config object within the class and set the `extra` attribute to "allow" or use it as `extra=Extra.allow` kwargs when declaring the model

Example from the [docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/) :

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, Extra


class Model(BaseModel, extra=Extra.forbid):
    a: str


try:
    Model(a='spam', b='oh no')
except ValidationError as e:
    print(e)
    """
    1 validation error for Model
    b
      extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
    """
```

Comment: I find it a little bit bizarre that the opposite of the solution is demonstrated in the answer. Just for the record, you'll want to use `class Model(BaseModel, extra=Extra.allow):` and then keyword arguments to the constructor will be instantiated as attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Putting an example using `extra.allow` that answers the question asked.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, Extra


class Model(BaseModel, extra=Extra.allow):
    a: str

my_model = Model(a="1")
my_model.b = "2"
# Model(a='1', b='2')
```

Comment: :How does your answer add a value to the existing (and accepted one) ? seems to be the same...

Comment: It uses `Extra.allow` instead of `Extra.forbid`. @Kwibus had the right suggestion, but the example he offers uses the opposite case. Refer to @NeilG's comment.

Comment: I suppose I could have suggested an edit to the existing answer instead